# Submit your literature reviews to our Tumblr!

Tags: discussion, faq, site-promotion, blog

Most of you probably aren't aware that Literature.SE has an unofficial Tumblr blog, called [One Minute Reviews](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/). This is supposed to be where Literature.SE users can submit short reviews of basically any work of literature. Note "short" - it is called *One Minute* Reviews, after all.

**What should I submit?**

Reviews. Reviews of novels, reviews of short stories, reviews of comics, reviews of autobiographies... anything's game. If it'd be on-topic on the main site, it's on-topic for the blog.

It should be relatively short, though. It's not an issue to submit a review that's not *super* short, just please avoid writing entire essays. Short to a bit long is fine; nobody is policing length that closely.

**How do I submit a review?**

Head to [the blog](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com). There's a hamburger menu on the top right of the page. Open it and click "submit".
Then, write your review. Please make sure to put the title of the work into the title of the post, and to mention who's writing the review + link to your profile at the end of the review. Then submit!

After submitting, your post will have to get approved. (You can blame spammers.) If you notice that it hasn't gone through after a day or so, ping Mithical or Gallifreyan in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room).

---

After you submit a review, your review might end up being linked from [our Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackLiterature), and maybe promoted a bit on other places.

---

I'd like to increase the number of reviews coming in; at the moment it's a bit small.

If you have any questions, I'd be happy to answer them down below.

Answer (score 11):

### List of all reviews on the Tumblr page

1. [*Rachel Rising* by Terry Moore](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/163299358450/review-rachel-rising-by-terry-moore), 22 July 2017, [Gallifreyan](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11/gallifreyan)
2. [*The Fifth Head of Cerberus* by Gene Wolfe](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/164109507500/review-the-fifth-head-of-cerberus-by-gene-wolfe), 12 August 2017, [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
3. [*Good Omens*, by Terry Pratchett and Neil Gaiman](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/177016984905/review-good-omens-by-terry-pratchett-and-neil), 15 August 2018, [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir)
4. [*The School for Good and Evil*, by Soman Chainani](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/183358092195/the-school-for-good-and-evil-by-soman-chainani), 10 March 2019, [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir)
5. [*Milkweed*, by Jerry Spinelli](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/183934307135/review-milkweed-by-jerry-spinelli), 4 April 2019, [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir)
6. [*Shantaram* by Gregory David Roberts](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/187370653730/review-shantaram-by-gregory-david-roberts), 30 August 2019, [CinCout](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/5526/cincout)
7. [*Matched* by Ally Condie](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/187596798825/review-matched-by-ally-condie), 9 September 2019, [CinCout](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/5526/cincout)
8. [*Rain Will Come* by Thomas Holgate](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/189437265585/review-rain-will-come-by-thomas-holgate), 2 December 2019, [CinCout](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/5526/cincout)
9. [*Running Out of Time*, by Margaret Peterson Haddix](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/189438094399/review-running-out-of-time-by-margaret), 2 December 2019, [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir)
10. [*Malgudi* Days (1982) by R. K. Narayan](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/617526565884116992/review-malgudi-days-1982-by-r-k-narayan), 8 May 2020, [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
11. [*Watership Down* by Richard Adams](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/647336174003912704/review-watership-down-by-richard-adams), 2 April 2021, [bobble](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11259/bobble)
12. [*Macbeth* (The RSC Shakespeare)](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/671438050827681792/macbeth-the-rsc-shakespeare), 24 December 2021, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
13. [Shakespeare Survey 26: Shakespeare’s Jacobean Tragedies](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/672864889844498432/shakespeare-survey-26-shakespeares-jacobean), 8 January 2022, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
14. [*Macbeth* (Norton Critical Editions)](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/676233648969842688/macbeth-norton-critical-editions), 15 February 2022, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
15. [*How to Read the Bible Like a Seminary Professor*](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/678094656179978240/how-to-read-the-bible-like-a-seminary-professor), 7 March 2022, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
16. [*Vögel, die verkünden Land*: A Biography of J. M. R. Lenz](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/699872898777759744/v%C3%B6gel-die-verk%C3%BCnden-land-a-biography-of-j-m-r), 3 November 2022, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
17. [*Shakespearean Tragedy* by A. C. Bradley](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/704335931852898304/shakespearean-tragedy-by-a-c-bradley), 22 December 2022, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
18. [*How to Read Shakespeare* by Nicholas Royle](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/704858087392231424/how-to-read-shakespeare-by-nicholas-royle), 28 December 2022, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
19. [*Macbeth* (The Oxford Shakespeare)](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/706218655316344832/macbeth-the-oxford-shakespeare), 12 January 2023, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
20. [*Macbeth: A Dagger of the Mind* by Harold Bloom](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/706438094317043712/macbeth-a-dagger-of-the-mind-by-harold-bloom), 14 January 2023, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
21. [*Shakespeare’s Tragic Heroes* by Lily B. Campbell](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/707863925772959744/shakespeares-tragic-heroes-by-lily-b-campbell), 30 January 2023, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
22. [*Shakespeare: A Very Short Introduction* by Stanley Wells](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/708341635180855296/shakespeare-a-very-short-introduction-by-stanley), 4 February 2023, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
23. [*Shakespeare* by Hans-Dieter Gelfert](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/708620657796218880/shakespeare-by-hans-dieter-gelfert), 7 February 2023, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
24. [*Blackbringer* by Laini Taylor](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/709233259106680832/blackbringer-by-laini-taylor), 14 February 2023, [DLosc](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1091/dlosc)
25. [*The Arden Introduction to Reading Shakespeare* by Jeremy Lopez](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/709839109044191232/the-arden-introduction-to-reading-shakespeare-by), 20 February 2023, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
26. [*Shakespeare auf 100 Seiten* by Stefana Sabin](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/post/714146626213642240/shakespeare-auf-100-seiten-by-stefana-sabin), 9 April 2023, [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)

Comment: ready to revive the blog?

Comment: @CinCout Always! But I'm not the person to ask - only Galli and Mith have admin access to approve new submissions to the blog.

Comment: @CinCout I think the Tumblr blog is very much alive now :-)

Comment: Let's keep it that way in 2023 :) @Tsundoku

Answer (score 7):

I'd love to participate in submitting reviews to the blog. However, I have the following two questions before I make up my mind:

1. Who owns the copyright to the content being published on the blog? I understand from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13976/who-owns-the-copyright-to-sofu-content) post on MSE that the content on SE network is licensed under "cc-wiki with attribution required". Does that also apply to the community-run blog?
2. Deriving from the first question, is it allowed to submit the review I already submitted on other review sites on the blog? Will the duplicate content cause any issue in terms of licensing, copyright, attribution, SEO, et al? Conversely, can I submit the same content that is first published on the blog to other review sites on the internet? One can safely assume that the content in question is originally generated by me, and is not copied/sourced from elsewhere.

Comment: See section six here:  https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/terms-of-service