# Why does Literature have a Tumblr blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

From [this](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/submit-your-literature-reviews-to-our-tumblr) post, we know that there is a dedicated blog on Tumblr. It is being used to publish reviews of works of literature. But reviews don't really fit under the QA model that SE sites follow.

Why, then, do we have a dedicated blog for Literature? Is it just to gain more eyeballs since we are still in the Beta phase? Or some other reason(s) altogether?

Comment: _"But reviews don't really fit under the QA model that SE sites follow"_ - neither do tweets, really, but a lot of SE sites have them. You have the reason right - it's all about eyeballs, or whatever sensory organ one uses to browse here. I imagine one other reason is to broaden the scope of the site, in this case by reading different books and publishing short reviews to encourage others to explore them.

Comment: Miiiight be related: [We will no longer be hosting Blog Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741), since some sites did have (official) blogs in the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> reviews don't really fit under the QA model that SE sites follow

You're absolutely right, and that's why these reviews are being published on an off-site blog instead of on the Q&A site.

Literature SE is a Q&A site, but it's also a *community* of people interested in literature, and there are a lot of things such a community might want to do which don't strictly fit into SE's Q&A model. For example:

- **Discussion** of scope, best practices, etc. We have meta for that.
- **Idle chatter** between community members getting to know each other. We have chat for that.
- **Promotion** of our site and its best posts elsewhere. We have Twitter for that. (Back in the day, every new SE site was given an associated Twitter account. So [older sites still have them](https://twitter.com/stackscifi?lang=en), but newer sites like this one [need to create their own](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17) - unofficial, community-maintained - Twitter accounts.)
- **Reviews** of things the community might be interested in (works of literature, in our case). Again, back in the day every new SE site was given an associated blog, hosted by SE but contributed to by the community. The official SE blogs were shut down a couple of years ago, but [some sites created their own](https://medium.com/universe-factory) - again, unofficial and community-maintained.

That's pretty much what happened here. Since SE no longer provides the platform for what used to be an official thing on every site, Literature SE's community stepped up to make it themselves. Reviews are absolutely not on-topic for the main site, but they're something our members might appreciate or want to take part in, so we have a separate side site for them.