# Announcing the February–March 2023 topic challenge: the works of Arthur Koestler

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the February–March 2023 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+5, -1), our 65th topic challenge will be

**the works of Arthur Koestler (1905 – 1983)**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during February and March 2023 you are invited to try to get hold of a work in sign language and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during February and March too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of one or more works by Arthur Koestler and

- asking good questions about it or
- answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
- writing a review of a book by or about Koestler on [our Tumblr blog](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139/2191).

Questions about these works should be tagged [arthur-koestler](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthur-koestler) and the work's title (if it is a book-length work).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Tsundoku's](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1250/2191):

> Arthur Koestler was a Hungarian-British author and journalist. He was born in Budapest and grew up mainly in Austria. He became a member of the Communist Party of Germany in 1931, from which he resigned in 1938 because he had become disillusioned by Stalinism. His works include the following:
>
> - [*The Gladiators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gladiators_(novel)) (novel, 1939). On the surface, this novel is about the effects of the Spartacus revolt in the Roman Republic, but it focuses on the theme of idealism going wrong.
> - [*Darkness at Noon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkness_at_Noon) (novel, 1940): the novel that made him famous. It is set during the Stalinist Great Purge of 1939. Curiously, Koestler's original manuscript was lost for almost 80 years and was [first translated into English in 2019](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2019/sep/24/darkness-at-noon-original-text-gets-first-english-translation-arthur-koestler).
> - [*Arrival and Departure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrival_and_Departure) (novel, 1943). In his review, George Orwell thought it contained "one of the most shocking descriptions of Nazi terrorism that have ever been written".
> - [*The Act of Creation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Act_of_Creation) (1964)
> - [*The Ghost in the Machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ghost_in_the_Machine) (1967; philosophical psychology)
> - [*The Sleepwalkers: A History of Man's Changing Vision of the Universe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sleepwalkers_(Koestler_book)) (1969)
> - [*Janus: A Summing Up*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus:_A_Summing_Up) (1978). This book develops the concept of [holarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holarchy), which "provides a coherent way of organizing knowledge and nature all together" (Wikipedia).

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191) or propose your own!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of all [questions posted in this topic challenge](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barthur-koestler%5D+created%3A2023-02..2023-03+is%3Aquestion)**

1. [Why did the book held by Rubashov change title between different versions of "Darkness at Noon"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24068/2191) by [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11734/), 10/02/2023 (201 views, 7 votes, 1 answer).
2. [What was Koestler's opinion of Hardy's translation of Darkness at Noon?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24135/) by [Zeus](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/7463/zeus), 20/02/2023 (453 views, HNQ, 7 votes, 2 answers).
3. [In what sense do The Gladiators, Darkness at Noon, and Arrival and Departure form a trilogy?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24168/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 22/02/2023 (61 views, 1 vote, 2 answers).
4. [In which language was The Gladiators first written?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24210/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 25/02/2023 (227 views, HNQ, 3 votes, 1 answer).
5. [Did Koestler coin "mimophant"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24325/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 12/03/2023 (625 views, HNQ, 5 votes, 2 answers).
6. [How historically accurate is Koestler's The Gladiators?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24426/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 24/03/2023 (36 view, 2 votes, no answer).
7. ...
8. *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2023.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these are [Why did the book held by Rubashov change title between different versions of "Darkness at Noon"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24068/) and [What was Koestler's opinion of Hardy's translation of Darkness at Noon?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24135/), with a score of 7 at the end of March.

The **most viewed** is [Did Koestler coin "mimophant"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24325/), with approximately 625 views during the months of February and March.

Five questions received at least one answer.

Reviews on our Tumblr blog: none.

---

Outside Literature Stack Exchange:

- [Is Koestler's ‘The Sleepwalkers’ still well regarded? Is there a more recent similar source?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/15200) by [Norman Gray](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/12870/), 01/03/2023 on History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange.