# Announcing the April–May 2023 topic challenge: the works of Abdulrazak Gurnah

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the April–May 2023 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+5), our 67th topic challenge will be

**the works of Abdulrazak Gurnah**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during April and May 2023 you are invited to try to get hold of a work by Abdulrazak Gurnah and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during April and May too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of one or more works by Abdulrazak Gurnah and

- asking good questions about it or
- answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
- writing a review of a book by or about Gurnah on [our Tumblr blog](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139/2191).

Questions about these works should be tagged [abdulrazak-gurnah](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abdulrazak-gurnah) and the work's title (if it is a book-length work).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine's](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/)
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1609/2191):

> Abdulrazak Gurnah is a Zanzibar-born (now Tanzania) novelist who won the 2021 Literature Nobel Prize for his works, especially his work on the impact of colonialism.
>
> The *Wall Street Journal* article on his Nobel prize is available [here](https://www.wsj.com/articles/nobel-prize-in-literature-awarded-to-novelist-abdulrazak-gurnah-11633605034?st=yb4ls7ii6v88ihv&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink).

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191) or propose your own!

Answer (score 4):

**List of all questions posted in this topic challenge**

1. [Why did Yusuf's father have a silver rupee in his pocket?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/why-did-yusufs-father-have-a-silver-rupee-in-his-pocket) by [EJoshuaS - Stand With Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine), 04/04/2023.
2. [Why did Gurnah title this story "Cages"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24551/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 08/04/2023.
3. [Why did Yusuf own both a Rosary and a Koran?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24596/why-did-yusuf-own-both-a-rosary-and-a-koran) by [EJoshuaS - Stand With Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine), 15/04/2023.
4. [Was Aziz actually Yusuf's uncle?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24641/was-aziz-actually-yusufs-uncle) by [EJoshuaS - Stand With Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine), 22/04/2023.
5. [Where is the story "Cages" set?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24889/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 29/05/2023.
6. *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2023.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[question URL]*, with a score of *TBD* at the end of May.

The **most viewed** is *[question URL]*, with approximately *TBD* views during the months of April and May.

*TBD* questions received at least one answer.

---

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: *TBD*.