# Announcing the June–July 2023 topic challenge: the works of Ales Adamovich

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/),
it is time to announce the June–July 2023 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+4, -0), our 69th topic challenge will be

**the works of Ales Adamovich**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/).
In short, during June and July 2023 you are invited to try to get hold of a work by Adamovich and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during June and July too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of one or more works by Ales Adamovich and

- asking good questions about it or
- answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
- writing a review of a book by or about Ales Adamovich on [our Tumblr blog](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139).

Questions about these works should be tagged [ales-adamovich](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ales-adamovich), [belarusian-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belarusian-language), and the work's title (if it is a book-length work).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Tsundoku's](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/)
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1535/):

> ### The works of Ales Adamovich
>
> [Ales Adamovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ales_Adamovich) (1927 – 1994) was a Belarusian writer and critic. Film buffs know him as the author of the screenplay for the anti-war film [*Come and See*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_and_See) (1985) (see [The Scariest Film Ever Made ISN'T a Horror Film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR0R7zsd7D8) on YouTube). His publications include the following:
>
> - *The Khatyn Story*, published in Belarusian in 1972; English translation: [*Khatyn*](https://glagoslav.com/shop/khatyn-by-ales-adamovych/) (Glagoslav Publications, 2012);
> - with Granin Daniil: [*Leningrad Under Siege: First-hand Accounts of the Ordeal*](https://www.pen-and-sword.co.uk/Leningrad-Under-Siege-Paperback/p/16429);
> - with Daniil Granin: [*A Book of the Blockade*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/book-of-the-blockade/oclc/277269479).
>
> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetlana_Alexievich#Literary_work), Svetlana Alexievich was influenced by Adamovich:
>
> > According to Russian writer and critic Dmitry Bykov, her books owe much to the ideas of Belarusian writer Ales Adamovich, who felt that the best way to describe the horrors of the 20th century was not by creating fiction but through recording the testimonies of witnesses.
>
> ---
>
> (Posted on 6 March 2021.)

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238) or propose your own!

Answer (score 1):

**List of all questions posted in this topic challenge**

1. [What is the "guilty smile of a blind man"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/what-is-the-guilty-smile-of-a-blind-man) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine)
2. ...
3. ...
4. *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2023.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[question URL]*, with a score of *TBD* at the end of July.

The **most viewed** is *[question URL]*, with approximately *TBD* views during the months of June and July.

*TBD* questions received at least one answer.

---

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: *TBD*.