# Announcing the December 2023 – January 2024 topic challenge: Henrik Ibsen

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

With apologies for the very late announcement of an event that should have already started ...

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/),
it is (long past) time to announce the December 2023 – January 2024 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+6/-1), the last topic challenge of this year and the first of the new year will be:

> ### Henrik Ibsen

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/). In short, during December 2023 and January 2024 you are invited to try to read at least one work by Henrik Ibsen and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during December and January too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of some works of Henrik Ibsen and asking (or answering!) good questions about them. Questions about these works should be tagged with [henrik-ibsen](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/henrik-ibsen) and [scandinavian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scandinavian-literature) and other tags as appropriate. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is Peter Shor's
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1783/17) of the topic:

> **Henrik Ibsen** was a very influential and highly regarded Norwegian playwright. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrik_Ibsen) claims that he is the “most frequently performed dramatist in the world after Shakespeare,” and calls him “one of the founders of modernism in theatre,” and “one of the most influential playwrights of his time.”
>
> We have six questions with the tag [henrik-ibsen], and only one of them has been answered — [How did Ibsen's writing in *A Doll's House* influence the James Joyce character Molly Bloom?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/how-did-ibsens-writing-in-a-dolls-house-influence-the-james-joyce-character-mo), which is only peripherally about Ibsen's play. So it seems that Ibsen has not been getting enough attention on this site.
>
> Ibsen's plays are generally entertaining; they often deal with interesting social and psychological issues, many of which are still relevant, and they have been very influential in the field of literature, on drama in particular. His plays are easy to find — they are out of copyright, and so can be found on Project Gutenberg. The meaning of some of his plays, in particuar *Rosmersholm*, is still being debated. Having a topic challenge on him will focus attention on him, and hopefully help us answer the existing questions on his plays and inspire new ones.

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/) (January–February), or propose your own topic!

Comment: Is the 'Tumblr blog' thing still relevant? I don't think I've seen any of those anywhere ever...

Comment: @CDR There've been [more than 20 posts](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1140/17), but activity tends to come in fits and starts.

Answer (score 1):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%henrik-ibsen%5D+created%3A2023-12-01..2024-01-31+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [Was Ibsen really so influential in the history of theatre?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26034/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 14/01/2024.
2. [Is the ending of A Doll's House satisfactory and moral?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26046/is-the-ending-of-a-dolls-house-satisfactory-and-moral) by [Dia](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/19398/dia), 15/01/2024.
3. [Is the title best translated "A Dollhouse", "A Doll House" or "A Doll's House"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26092/17) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289), 23/01/2024.
4. [Was Agatha Christie's short story "Magnolia Blossom" inspired by Ibsen?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26096/17) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289), 24/01/2024.
5. [Did Ibsen have any known response to Shaw's Quintessence of Ibsenism?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26113/17) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289), 26/01/2024.

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Was Ibsen really so influential in the history of theatre?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26034/17), with a score of 6 at the end of January.

The **most viewed** is [Is the title best translated "A Dollhouse", "A Doll House" or "A Doll's House"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26092), with approximately 139 views by the end of January.

3 questions received at least one answer.

---

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: *TBD*.